# Can I force a Codec to decode H264 data to a particular ColorFormat (from the ColorFormats it supports)?

Tags: android, decode, h.264, yuv, android-mediacodec

On Android 4.1 and above, I am using `MediaCodec` framework to decode H264 data. I see the codec instance that I'm using (via `createDecoderByType`) supports multiple color-formats. However, it always gives the output in the 1st-indexed color-format (from its supported list).

Is there a way to force the decoder to give out decoded data in a particular color-format from the ColorFormats it supports? I know the developer docs does mention that the key `KEY_COLOR_FORMAT` can only be set for encoders, but then help me understand what is the rational of having multiple supported color-formats for decoders?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is currently no way to specify the color format for the decoder output.

This is especially annoying on devices that use undocumented proprietary buffer layouts.

Directing the output to a Surface results in more consistent and portable behavior, but as of API 19 there's still no convenient way to get at the pixel data ([ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) doesn't work with MediaCodec output formats, `glReadPixels()` can be slow and works in RGB, etc).  If you can do what you need with OpenGL shaders then things work pretty well (see e.g. the effects in "[show + capture camera](https://github.com/google/grafika)").

Comment: Or are there native color-filters available for converting decoder output data from one format to another?

Comment: None are provided via public API in the platform.  The ByteBuffer output of the video decoder is not very useful unless you're only targeting specific devices.